# Axios error status code UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

Using axios, I'm making GET requests to multiple links to test to see if they are broken links. If the GET requests returns an error, I want to log this error to the console and send it to the client side with socket. However, on *some* links (not all), I get an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

```
// check if the link is dead
axios.get(linkHref, {
   auth: {
     username: USERNAME,
     password: PASSWORD
   }
})
.then( (response) => {
  if (response.status != 200) {
    resultData = {
      text: linkText,
      url: linkHref,
      statusCode: String(response.status)
    }
    console.log(resultData);
    io.sockets.emit("result", resultData); // send link to client-side
  }
})
.catch( (error) => {
if (error) {
    resultData = {
      text: linkText,
      url: linkHref,
      statusCode: String(error.response.status) // this is where the error is
   }
   console.log(resultData);
   io.sockets.emit("result", resultData); // send link to client-side
  }
});
```

I expect it work correctly and return the status code of the error but sometimes I get a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` error. But with my if statement in the `.catch`, I am checking to make sure that there *is* an error and that it is not undefined so I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

EDIT: Also, this works (does not show me that error) when I run it on my Mac but not in Windows ... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined` The *response* property on error.response is not defined eg `error = { response: undefined }`. Therefore, referencing any properties on it throws an error. `error.response[property]`

*Also* on failed/hanging http requests the *error* argument is different. Checkout this gist [axios-catch-error](https://gist.github.com/fgilio/230ccd514e9381fafa51608fcf137253). The *error* argument will have different properties for this case.

Answer (score 0):

hey can you check by  validating whether you are getting the response property on the error object in the if else condition

```
.catch( (error) => {
if (error.response) {
   //rest of the code...
  }
});
```